# How to pass dynamic parameter value in a link using Struts taglib?

Tags: java, jsp, struts, struts-1, taglib

I'm trying to use Struts framework in my project. I want to use the `html:button` to send parameter in the link but I don't understand how to make it.

In other words, I want to translate this line:

```
<input type="button" onClick="window.location.href='resum.do?action=ViewMessage&&id_message=<%= id_msg %>'" value="View"/>
```

to Struts taglib, something like this:

```
<html:button property="" onclick="window.location.href='resum.do?action=ViewMessage&&id_message=<%= id_msg %>'" value="View"></html:button>
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Don't use Struts1 anymore, use Struts2. Struts1 is EOL (End Of Life). Deprecated. Dead. Not good for starting new projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `html:button` tag is used only inside the `form` tag. See the [docs](http://exclamationlabs.github.io/struts-1.3.10_docs/struts-taglib/tagreference.html#html:button)

> This tag is only valid when nested inside a form tag body.

Also set the property attribute.